# Get String Value of Blob Passed to e.parameter in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, blob

I'm using this code to get a blob passed to a function:

```
function submit(e){
  var arrayBlob = e.parameter.arrayBlob;
  Logger.log("arrayBlob #2 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString());
```

This is the error I get:

> Execution failed: TypeError: Can not find getDataAsString function in
>   the Blob object.'arrayBlob'

How do I get the string value of this blob?

Here is my code:

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
    var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
    var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
      if (thesesType != ''){
         var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
         arrayList.push(newArray);
         break;
         }
      }
   }
  arrayList.sort();
  var result = userProperties.getProperty('savedArray');
    arrayList =  JSON.stringify(arrayList);
    var arrayBlob = Utilities.newBlob(arrayList);
    Logger.log("arrayBlob #1 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString()); // Here it`s OK
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(550).setHeight(450);
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
                   .setId('panel');
    panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayBlob', arrayBlob)); 
    var label = app.createLabel("Selecione os itens desejados").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
    app.add(label);
    arrayList =  JSON.parse(arrayList);
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      Logger.log("arrayList[i][0] = " + arrayList[i][0]);
      Logger.log("arrayList[i] ====> " + arrayList[i]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
   }
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
   panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);
   scroll.add(panel);
   app.add(scroll);
   mydoc.show(app);
}

function submit(e){
  var arrayBlob = e.parameter.arrayBlob;
  Logger.log("arrayBlob #2 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString()); 


 // Continues...
}
```

I'd like the solution worked with more than one user simultaneous using the script.

Comment: Was this formerly working, and recently stopped working?  The code is using Class **UiInstance** which is now deprecated. [Google Documentation - Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance)

Comment: This code is embedding a blob in a hidden element of the dialog box.  It seems that this is the attempted method being used to pass the blob.  I would put the data into a global variable instead.  I'm not sure why a blob is being used rather than just an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using Blob's here at all, you could simply work with JSON instead.

However, if you have a reason to use Blobs, you can pass the JSON data through your form and create the Blob in your handler, as the modified code below does:

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
    var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
    var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
      if (thesesType != ''){
         var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
         arrayList.push(newArray);
         break;
         }
      }
   }
  arrayList.sort();

  var result = UserProperties.getProperty('savedArray');

  //get JSON data pass through form. 
  var arrayBlob = JSON.stringify(arrayList);   

  var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(550).setHeight(450);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
  .setId('panel');

  //include JSON Data in the form.
  panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayBlob', arrayBlob));  

  var label = app.createLabel("Selecione os itens desejados").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
  app.add(label);

  panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length)); 
  for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){
    var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
    Logger.log("arrayList[i][0] = " + arrayList[i][0]);
    Logger.log("arrayList[i] ====> " + arrayList[i]);
    panel.add(checkbox);
  }
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
  panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);
  mydoc.show(app);
}

function submit(e){
  var arrayBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.arrayBlob);
  Logger.log("arrayBlob #2 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString()); 

 // Continues...
}
```

In the method you were using originally, the Blob itself was never included in the form, you were simply passing the string "Blob" around.

This is because the function createHidden(name, value); expects two strings as parameters, so it calls ".toString()" on the arrayBlob object, which returns the string "Blob".

Comment: I've tryied exactly your code, but get this error mesage: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: a`

Comment: sounds like an error elsewhere in your script, since you saw the same error when trying Sandy Goods response.  Try testing the above code in a new script and you'll find it works.

Answer (score 2):

### Update:

Add a global variable ***OUTSIDE*** of any function:

```
var arrayBlob = Utilities.newBlob("dummy data");

function showList(folderID) {
   Code here ....
};
```

Check that the code has access to the blob:

```
function submit(e){
  Logger.log("arrayBlob.getDataAsString(): " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString());
  //More Code . . . 
}
```

This solution eliminates the need of embedding a hidden element in the dialog box with a value of the blob.

You won't need this line:

```
panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayBlob', arrayBlob));
```

There are other changes I'd make to the code, but I simply want to show the main issue.

### Old Info:

In the function `showList()`, the method `getDataAsString()` works on the blob named `arrayBlob`.

```
Logger.log("arrayBlob #1 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString()); // Here it`s OK
```

In the function, `submit()`, the same method does not work.

```
var arrayBlob = e.parameter.arrayBlob;
```

In the function `showList()`, the code is assigning a newBlob to the variable `arrayBlob`.  So `arrayBlob` is available to have the `getDataAsString()` method used on it.

```
var arrayBlob = Utilities.newBlob(arrayList);
```

In the function, `submit()`, you are trying to pass the `arrayBlob` blob variable into the `submit()` function, and reference it with `e.parameter`.

If you put a `Logger.log()` statement in the `submit()` function.

```
function submit(e){
  Logger.log('e: ' + e);
  Logger.log('e.parameter` + e.parameter);

  var arrayBlob = e.parameter.arrayBlob;
```

Those Logger.log statements should show something in them.  If there is nothing in `e.parameter`, then there is nothing for the `.getDataAsString()` to work on.

It looks like you are putting the arrayBlob into a hidden panel.

```
panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayBlob', arrayBlob));
```

But when the object is getting passed to the `submit(e)` function, the `arrayBlob` might not be getting put into that object.

So, what I'm saying is, the:

```
Logger.log("arrayBlob #2 = " + arrayBlob.getDataAsString());
```

Line may be perfectly good, but there is no `arrayBlob` there to work on.  This hasn't fixed your problem, but do you think I'm understanding part of what is going on?

Comment: Thanks, @Sandy Good! Buth the e.parameter is the method from the callback element (and `arrayBlob` is the name of the variable).

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation.  I'm just trying to figure this out.

Comment: Of course, here it is: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/server-handler (I never was good with handlers)

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.  I starting to figure it out now.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, you put exactly my doubt. Why the blob value of the variable `arrayBlob` is not passing through the `e.parameter.arrayBlob`

Comment: Thanks, @SandyGood. It's a good solution! But, for my purpose, if two users use the script at the same time, it will change the blob value. Do you have an idea for simultaneous use of the script (each use with its blob value)? (I'll create another question on that)

Comment: If you used HTML Service, you could store the blob in HTML.  There is the Cache service, but you have to much data to put into Cache.