# Why this try of recovering an array from the `e.parameter.variableName` method is not working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What is going wrong with this code? When I log the array list, before the `sumbit` function, its ok (with the expected content and position of elements inside it's arrays). But, when I get it through `e.parameter.arrayList`it doesn't have the same value, neither it's elements. How to fix that?

```
function showList(folderID) {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolderById(folderID);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var arrayList = [];
  for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
    var thesesName = file.getName();
    var thesesId = file.getId();
    var thesesDoc = DocumentApp.openById(thesesId);
    for (var child = 0; child < thesesDoc.getNumChildren(); child++){
    var thesesFirstParagraph = thesesDoc.getChild(child);
    var thesesType = thesesFirstParagraph.getText();
      if (thesesType != ''){
         var newArray = [thesesName, thesesType, thesesId];
         arrayList.push(newArray);
         break;
         }
      }
   }
    arrayList.sort();
    var mydoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(550).setHeight(450);
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel()
                   .setId('panel');

    var label = app.createLabel("Choose your theses").setStyleAttribute("fontSize", 18);
    app.add(label);
    panel.add(app.createHidden('checkbox_total', arrayList.length));
    panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayList', arrayList)); 
    Logger.log(" arrayList before submit = " + arrayList);


    for(var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){      
      var checkbox = app.createCheckBox().setName('checkbox_isChecked_'+i).setText(arrayList[i][0]);
      Logger.log("arrayList[i][0] = " + arrayList[i][0]);
      Logger.log("arrayList[i] ====> " + arrayList[i]);
      panel.add(checkbox);
   }
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('submit').addCallbackElement(panel);
   panel.add(app.createButton('Submit', handler));
   var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(500, 400);  
  scroll.add(panel);
  app.add(scroll);
  mydoc.show(app);


}

function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) // if we find a match, return true
            return true;    }
    return false; // if we got here, there was no match, so return false
 }

function submit(e){
   Logger.log(" arrayList = " + arrayList);
  var arrayList = e.parameter.arrayList;
  var numberOfItems = Number(e.parameter.checkbox_total);
  var thesesArrays = [];
  var usedThesesType = [];
  var usedThesesName = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
    if(e.parameter['checkbox_isChecked_'+i] == 'true'){
     Logger.log(" arrayList inside for loop = " + arrayList);
      Logger.log(" arrayList[i] = " + arrayList[i]);
      thesesArrays.push(arrayList[i]);
      usedThesesType.push(arrayList[i][1]);
            Logger.log(" arrayList[i][1] = " + arrayList[i][1]);

      usedThesesName.push(arrayList[i][0]); 
       Logger.log(" arrayList[i][0] = " + arrayList[i][0]);
     }
   }
  var allThesesTypeArray = []; // To control Theses type apparence in the final doc
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
     var thesesType = arrayList[i][1];
     if ( !(include(allThesesTypeArray, thesesType)) ){
        allThesesTypeArray.push(thesesType);     }
   }
  var targetDocId = userProperties.getProperty('targetDocId');
  for (var i = 0; i < thesesArrays.length; i++) {
     var thesesType = thesesArrays[i][1];
    Logger.log(" thesesArrays = " + thesesArrays);
     var thesesId = thesesArrays[i][2];
     importTheses(targetDocId, thesesId, thesesType);       
    }   
  cleanNotUsedThesesTitles(targetDocId, allThesesTypeArray, usedThesesType);
  if(userProperties.getProperty('atLeastOneTheseType') == 0){
      Browser.msgBox('There was no theses inside your model. Check it!');
  }  
  var joinAndInsert = userProperties.getProperty('joinAndInsert');  
  showURL(usedThesesName, joinAndInsert);
  return UiApp.getActiveApplication().close();
}
```

Comment: So, the `submit(e)` function is triggered from a Form associated with a spreadsheet?  And you have a trigger set up with the name of the function as "submit"?

Comment: What are the values you are getting from `e`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't simply pass an Array into a form field and get the value of that array back. This is the exact same problem as you asked about on [Get String Value of Blob Passed to e.parameter in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805250/get-string-value-of-blob-passed-to-e-parameter-in-apps-script/) . The only difference is now you are trying to pass an Array around instead of a Blob.

You can only pass Strings as the value of the field, so you need to convert your data (arrayList) into a string.  Then you need to convert that string back into an Array.  Do this using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

Change

```
panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayList', arrayList));
```

to

```
panel.add(app.createHidden('arrayList', JSON.stringify(arrayList)));
```

and change

```
var arrayList = e.parameter.arrayList;
```

to

```
 var arrayList = JSON.parse(e.parameter.arrayList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be getting an object being passed and assigned to the `e` argument.  You can iterate through that object to see what the properties and the values are:

```
function submit(e) {
  Logger.log("submit ran: " + e);
  Logger.log("values?: " + e.values);

  for(var propertyName in e) {

    Logger.log("propertyName: " + propertyName);
    Logger.log("This property value is: " + e[propertyName]);
    Logger.log(" ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But neither so I got to figure out what was happening

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake because you have written:

```
for (var file in files) {
    file = files[file];
```

where the variable file is the index of your array, so you are changing that value in your bucle.
Have you tried to use another name like:

```
for (var file in files) {
    f = files[file];
```